# Training CNN with Keras was fast, now it is many times slower

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I was training a CNN with 120 thousand pictures, and it was ok. About 320 seconds per epoch.

```
3073/3073 [==============================] - 340s 110ms/step - loss: 0.4146 - accuracy: 0.8319 - val_loss: 0.3776 - val_accuracy: 0.8489
Epoch 2/20
3073/3073 [==============================] - 324s 105ms/step - loss: 0.3462 - accuracy: 0.8683 - val_loss: 0.3241 - val_accuracy: 0.8770
Epoch 3/20
3073/3073 [==============================] - 314s 102ms/step - loss: 0.3061 - accuracy: 0.8878 - val_loss: 0.2430 - val_accuracy: 0.9052
Epoch 4/20
3073/3073 [==============================] - 327s 107ms/step - loss: 0.2851 - accuracy: 0.8977 - val_loss: 0.2236 - val_accuracy: 0.9149
Epoch 5/20
3073/3073 [==============================] - 318s 104ms/step - loss: 0.2725 - accuracy: 0.9033 - val_loss: 0.2450 - val_accuracy: 0.9119
Epoch 6/20
3073/3073 [==============================] - 309s 101ms/step - loss: 0.2642 - accuracy: 0.9065 - val_loss: 0.2168 - val_accuracy: 0.9218
Epoch 7/20
3073/3073 [==============================] - 311s 101ms/step - loss: 0.2589 - accuracy: 0.9083 - val_loss: 0.1996 - val_accuracy: 0.9286
Epoch 8/20
3073/3073 [==============================] - 317s 103ms/step - loss: 0.2538 - accuracy: 0.9110 - val_loss: 0.2653 - val_accuracy: 0.9045
Epoch 9/20
3073/3073 [==============================] - 1346s 438ms/step - loss: 0.2497 - accuracy: 0.9116 - val_loss: 0.2353 - val_accuracy: 0.9219
Epoch 10/20
3073/3073 [==============================] - 1434s 467ms/step - loss: 0.2457 - accuracy: 0.9141 - val_loss: 0.1943 - val_accuracy: 0.9326`
```

Then, after a few tests, it became 12x (times) slower. With the same parameters. I thought it was because the CPU got too hot, but it never worked like before again. I tried reseting my keras session, tried reinstalling Ubuntu 18.04, tried setting up my GPU, tried installing on conda, but none of these worked. Also tried other codes, with different datasets, which are also slower. Quite frustrating.

No other symptom of a burnt CPU problem. Everything runs as always did.
Tensorflow 2.2.0

I would appreciate some help.

Edit: actually, if I wait one hour, it gets back to normal speed! Now I think it could be some problem with the first import from the disk into the memory.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.preprocessing import image
import os


#======= GPU
#os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1" #disables GPU
#os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '4' #verbose
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras import backend as K
K.clear_session()
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession

config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)

K.set_session(session)
#======= GPU



print(tf.__version__)

callbacks = [
    tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
        # Stop training when `val_loss` is no longer improving
        monitor='val_accuracy',
        # "no longer improving" being defined as "no better than 1e-2 less"
        min_delta=1e-3,
        # "no longer improving" being further defined as "for at least 2 epochs"
        patience=2,
        verbose=1)
]

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

#flow_from_directory knows categories are divided by folders
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set', #applies a method to the object
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32, #minibatch
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')
print(training_set.class_indices)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
                                            target_size = (64, 64), #has to be the same as that of the training set
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')

cnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential() #an ANN base

#convolution
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=[64, 64, 3])) #convolutional layer
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2)) #maxPooling

#new convolution
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')) #remove input_shape
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))

cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())

cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))

cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, activation='softmax'))

cnn.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

print("Got here.")
cnn.fit(x = training_set, validation_data = test_set, epochs = 20)

# serialize model to JSON
model_json = cnn.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5
cnn.save_weights("model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk.")
```

Comment: Because it is in the middle of training I suspect something else is blocking your CPU. Are you using some kind of shared computer/cluster? Check if anything is running in the background.

Comment: It is my personal laptop. No sharing.

Comment: Actually, if I wait one hour, it gets back to normal speed! Now I think it could be some problem with the first import from the disk into the memory.

Comment: If its a laptop, then it could just be CPU frequency scaling

Comment: Just set them all to "performance", but nothing changed.